# OnCacheAuthorization override

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I would like to write my own `OnCacheAuthorization` method for asp.net mvc, so I would control the user access to the site.

I wrote my own logging system, so that after you log in you have to enter some more data until the account is authorized (I control this through a varibale). So if a user doesn't finish the the procedure, he cannot visit other pages on the site.

I wrote the following method:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);


    var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
    String culture = HttpContext.Current.Session["Culture"].ToString();
    var identity = httpContext.User.Identity;
    MembershipUser userMembership = Membership.GetUser(identity.Name);
    Guid userId = new Guid(userMembership.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
    String redirectUrl = "~/" + culture + "/Error/UserRegistrationNotFinished";
    httpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
    filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();

    if ((!userMembership.IsApproved) && AuthorizeCore( filterContext.HttpContext ))
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, true);
    }
    else
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString(),true); 
    }
}
```

This method works. If the user did not finish his login procedure, he is correctly rerouted to `UserRegistrationNotFinished` page. The problem is that if the login procedure is finished, the method doesn't let him go to the page he entered in the URL. I only get a blank page and the method loops.

How can I write this method, that it will work for approved users as well?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, I missunderstood the whole concept. Here is the solution that works:

```
public class ActivationRequiredAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string _redirectUrl;
    private bool _failedValidation;

    public ActivationRequiredAttribute()
    {
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        UserInfoRepository _userInfoRepository = new UserInfoRepository();
        var identity = httpContext.User.Identity;
        MembershipUser userMembership = Membership.GetUser(identity.Name);
        Guid userId = new Guid(userMembership.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
        userInfo _userInfo = _userInfoRepository.GetUser(userId);

        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        if ((httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) && (userMembership.IsApproved)&&(_userInfo.userStatus == 1))
        {
            _failedValidation = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            _failedValidation = false;
            return false;
        }

        // return false;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        String redirectUrl = "~/Error/UserRegistrationNotFinished";

        if (!_failedValidation)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, true);
            //filterContext.Result = View(,)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two quick comments.  First, action filter attributes *must* be stateless.  The same instance of the attribute might be used to service multiple requests, so the _failedValidation flag set by one request may accidentally be read by a different request.  Second, *never* call Response.Redirect() from an MVC application.  It doesn't actually prevent the rest of the pipeline from executing, so your controller can still end up being called.  Return a RedirectResult instead.

Comment: Tested this theory, and it is in fact bad. Try this: Login with an authorized user, then log out. Now revoke that authorization in the database and try to log in again (it fails, of course). Now grant that authorization back to the user and try to log in again... it fails because the validation failure is still in a failed state since OnAuthorization gets called before AuthorizeCore ... sad panda